# Concatenating pandas dataframe on basis of increasing index number and retaining their positon on basis of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Edited:

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
  Class  Sex  SibSp Fare
0  0      0     0     0
2  2      2     2     2
3  3      3     3     3
5  5      5     5     5
```

I have another pandas dataframe as follows:

```
  Class  Sex  SibSp Fare
1  1      1     1     1
4  4      4     4     4
```

If I concate these 2 dataframe using

```
pd.concat([traindf,testdf])
```

I get the following result:

```
  Class  Sex  SibSp Fare
0  0      0     0     0
2  2      2     2     2
3  3      3     3     3
5  5      5     5     5
1  1      1     1     1
4  4      4     4     4
```

However, I want to get result as follows:

```
   Class  Sex  SibSp Fare
0  0      0     0     0
1  1      1     1     1
2  2      2     2     2
3  3      3     3     3
4  4      4     4     4
5  5      5     5     5
```

I have used `pd.concat([traindf,testdf]).sort_values()` but this does not work. Any idea on how to accomplish this so that dataframes are concatenated based on their index numbers. Thanks

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from sample data? Is possible add `Age` column to sample data? [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: No, I cant add `Age` column to sample data since I filled in Age values using Linear Regression based on other features that are available in the dataframe

Comment: You could also not slit the df in 2 by working on df[df['Age'].isnull()] directly.

Comment: I had to slit the df into 2 since I am training the Linear Regression on the rows where Age value is not null and then trying to predict the value of Age on 2nd df where Age value is null. If I hadn't sliced df into 2 I wouldn't have been able to train the Linear Regression model because of NULL values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need sorting by index use:

```
df = pd.concat([traindf,testdf]).sort_index()
```

Or if need sorting by column `Class` use:

```
df = pd.concat([traindf,testdf]).sort_values(by=['Class'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly fill in the ages without splitting the dataframes.  But if you have to split them, then you can use the following:

```
pd.concat([traindf, testdf], sort=False).sort_index()
```

Comment: Then ouput is same like original DataFrame, if correct code, this raise error ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all the columns then you can get the slice using `loc` and just overwrite it.

```
# Create some dummy dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Pclass': np.random.randint(0,10,10),
        'Fare': np.random.randint(0,10,10),
        'Age': np.random.randint(0,100,10)
    })
df2 = copy.deepcopy(df1[df1['Fare']%2 == 0]*1.5)
print (df1, df2)

# Owerwrite df1 with df2
for i in df2.index:
  if i in df1.index:
    df1.loc[i] = df2.loc[i]

print ("After overwrite")
print (df1)
```

Output:

```
   Pclass  Fare  Age
0       7     6   25
1       8     3   34
2       0     4   57
3       9     1   98
4       3     5   58
5       8     0   97
6       9     6   53
7       2     0    1
8       0     5   33
9       2     9   36

   Pclass  Fare    Age
0    10.5   9.0   37.5
2     0.0   6.0   85.5
5    12.0   0.0  145.5
6    13.5   9.0   79.5
7     3.0   0.0    1.5

After overwrite

   Pclass  Fare    Age
0    10.5   9.0   37.5
1     8.0   3.0   34.0
2     0.0   6.0   85.5
3     9.0   1.0   98.0
4     3.0   5.0   58.0
5    12.0   0.0  145.5
6    13.5   9.0   79.5
7     3.0   0.0    1.5
8     0.0   5.0   33.0
9     2.0   9.0   36.0
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Kindly read it. This method though works, doesn't suit me as I don't have any duplicate index values in both my dataframes.